# View does not print database column value (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-cloud-storage

The title could also be: update_column statement does not save value in database, despite logs indicating that this happened.

I want to upload PDF files to Google Cloud Storage, to get started I downloaded Google's sample Rails application which I got to work perfectly (uploads and downloads)
I then copied the code into my own application (see relevant files below) and file *UPloading* works as well.

However, for some reason, inside the upload.rb model file, when the `file` database columnm is updated with the correct url of the pdf_file on Google Cloud, the value is not saved in the database. 
The logs indicate that it is saved as you can see in the line `SQL (0.3ms)  UPDATE "uploads" SET "file" = 'https://pdf-uploads.storage.googleapis.com/uploads/2/Selection_002.png' WHERE "uploads"."id" = ?  [["id", 2]]`. When I try to retreive the link in my view to display it, the file column seems to be empty.

**Web server logs**

```
 begin transaction
   SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "uploads" ("songname", "artist", "album", "level", "video", "user_id", "genre_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["songname", "Hello"], ["artist", "Adele"], ["album", "Hello - Single"], ["level", 1], ["video", ""], ["user_id", 1], ["genre_id", 5], ["created_at", "2015-12-25 05:19:42.601108"], ["updated_at", "2015-12-25 05:19:42.601108"]]
   SQL (0.3ms)  UPDATE "uploads" SET "file" = 'https://pdf-uploads.storage.googleapis.com/uploads/2/Selection_002.png' WHERE "uploads"."id" = ?  [["id", 2]]
   (3.6ms)  commit transaction
```

**upload.rb Model File**

```
attr_accessor :file

private

after_create :upload_file, if: :file

def upload_file
  file_object = StorageBucket.files.new(
      key: "uploads/#{id}/#{file.original_filename}",
      body: file.read,
      public: true
  )

  file_object.save

# this is what is causing the problem
  update_columns file: file_object.public_url

end
```

**uploads_controller.rb**

```
def create
@upload = current_user.uploads.build(upload_params)
if params[:genre_id].blank?
    @upload.genre = Genre.find_by_name('Uncategorized')
else
    @upload.genre = Genre.find_by_id(params[:genre_id])
end
if @upload.level.blank?
    @upload.level = 3
end

  respond_to do |format|
    if @upload.save
      format.html { redirect_to @upload, notice: 'Upload was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @upload }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @upload.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Check the new entry from the rails console

```
Upload.last
Upload Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "uploads".* FROM "uploads"  ORDER BY "uploads"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
=> #<Upload id: 2, songname: "Hello", artist: "Adele", album: "Hello - Single", level: 1, video: "", file: "https://pdf-uploads.storage.googleapis.com/uploads...", downloads: 0, views: 2, user_id: 1, genre_id: 5, created_at: "2015-12-25 05:19:42", updated_at: "2015-12-25 05:20:07">
```

As you can see it inserted a value in the file column (which is truncated for some reason...not sure if that is just to keep the output short or if a truncated value was actually stored in the database.
`file: "https://pdf-uploads.storage.googleapis.com/uploads..."`
Now, that's where the problems start.
In my view I have this line of code `Upload URL: <%= @upload.file.to_s %>` to print out the database file column and it prints nothing (like file attribute is blank.). Like I explained, I checked that the column is definitely not blank

I used the table_print gem to print the database table from the rails console, and it shows the file column as a blank column (again, no idea why it would do that. Rails record printer shows that a *truncated url* is stored in the database)

Again, I spend hours figuring this out last night and I can not figure it out by myself. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you try printing `@upload.album` or some other field and see if it's getting printed? Also try giving `puts "\nURL #{@upload.file}\n"` in controller or view and check.

Comment: Yes the other columns print fine :) Forgot to mention that. I tried what you suggested. `puts "\nURL #{@upload.file}\n"` prints "URL" and the space but not the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments at [new problem after removing attr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34460346/view-does-not-print-database-column-value-ruby-on-rails#comment-56663118) are due to the variable 'file' being a string.  If you were to `file.is_a? String` Ruby would confirm this.  I'm assuming file is a URL:

> ```
> => #<Upload id: 2, songname: "Hello", 
>    artist: "Adele", album: "Hello - Single",
>    level: 1, video: "", 
>    file: "https://pdf-uploads.storage.googleapis.com/uploads...", 
>    downloads: 0, views: 2, user_id: 1, genre_id: 5, 
>    created_at: "2015-12-25 05:19:42", updated_at: "2015-12-25 05:20:07">
> ```

The new error is caused because there is no method original_filename in String.  The attr_accessor file overrides the behavior in the model to allow passing in an object as a file which updates the column file with an instance of the passed file object from the parameters.

Removing attr_accessor will allow the string to be retrieved from the database (so you could `<%= @upload.file.to_s %>`).  However, if you have the attr_accesor in there, your empty instance variable returns.

So how do you get the path to display on the view when you are overriding the getter?

1. rename the `attr_accessor file`
2. change `attr_accessor` to `attr_writter` to maintain updating file by passing a tempfile in the params but returning the string
3. create an instance method for the getter of `attributes[:file]`

I'm thinking number 2 would be the easiest, but there may be some serious downstream implications.  Implementing #3 would look something like:

```
# app/models/upload.rb
  def file_path
    attributes['file']
  end

# app/views/uploads/index.html.erb
  <%= @upload.file_path %>
```

Comment: I think file_path needs to prepend `self.` to the attributes.

Answer (score 1):

`attr_accessor` is creating problem for you.

Why are you using it? You have the field already in database.

If rails3 use `attr_accessible` rails4 `strong_params`.

edit:

remove `attr_accessor :file`

in your uploads_controller, add `file` field to `upload_params` method.

Comment: I'm using it because the Google sample application used it. Can you expand that answer? I am using Rails 4.2.5. What do i have to do to make `strong_params` work?

Comment: Thanks, I now get this: `undefined method `original_filename' for "#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007faf0166df98>":String` on the line
`key: "uploads/#{id}/#{file.original_filename}",` in upload_file. The parameters passed clearly contain an original_filename. See here:
`"file"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007faf0166df98 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20151225-35702-1tk2x1r.jpg>,
 @original_filename="images.jpg",
 @content_type="image/jpeg",
 @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"upload[file]\"; filename=\"images.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}`

Comment: it would not relate to this question, although you must be using carrierwave, permit those related parameters in `upload_params` method.

Comment: I am not using carrierwave. I am using gcloud (which uses fog). I have those gems in my Gemfile. If I created a new question, it would contain exactly the same information on this page. What is the point?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you permit all the related params for uploading, including :file

```
# app/controllers/uploads_controller.rb
class UploadsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    ...
  end

  private

  def upload_params
    params.require(:some_required_param).permit(:genre_id, :file)
  end
end
```

Then make sure you have **:multipart => true** on your form

```
# some_view.html.erb
<%= form_tag({:action => "create"}, :method => :post, :multipart => true do %>
```

Comment: the parameter is permitted. I am using simple_form with multi_part enabled.
`<%= simple_form_for(@upload, :html => {:multipart => true}, class: "form-horizontal") do |f| %>`